# How to turn off wifi light on keyboard in windows 10

Tags: wireless-networking

My laptop wireless adapter doesn't support the new fiber optic internet. Hence I'm using the internet through a USB wifi card.

I have uninstalled both the wireless network card and the HP wireless button from the device manager. Yet the wifi light on the keyboard doesn't turn off.

My laptop HP 15-e034TX. I'm using Windows 10.

How do I turn off the wifi light on the keyboard?

Thanks.

Comment: Since you're connected to WiFi through the USB adapter, why should you want to disable the indicator for the connection?

Comment: The light remains turned on(white) even if I unplug the Wi-Fi USB. Also anyway the light remains turned on either white or red.

Comment: I guess the color means connected or not?

Comment: yes, white connected, red disconnected. In my case, it is always white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the WiFi indicator light is not functioning correctly in your
computer.

Windows itself doesn't seem to have a setting for disabling it.
You might be able to find some setting of the network driver to disable
this indicator.

If the driver has such a setting, it will usually be found in
*Device manager > Network Adapters > Your wireless adapter > Properties >
Advanced*. Look for something with the word "state" or similar.
Be careful, and reboot might be required to apply the setting.

If you can't find such a setting, and if physically disconnecting
the light is not an easy option, then there's no solution
(except perhaps for using a bit of a sticky tape).

Comment: It worked well in windows 7 but when I changed to windows 10 it isn't functioning correctly. I tried disabling and uninstalling the driver in the device manager, still the light is white.

Comment: Look for a setiing of the driver, as described above. The Windows 10 driver wouldn't be the same as in Windows 7. Which driver are you using?

Comment: Thanks. Now the light turned red. Under Advanced I disabled the Radio on/off, option and restarted. The light is red now.